# Issue with RadioButton with RadioGroup in Android using a toggle feature/isChecked and cleaning code up

Tags: java, android, android-radiobutton

Hi I been trying for a while and going through lots of theories and stack answers. Though I just can't figure out how to take the code below for a simple trivia app, using a RadioButton in a RadioGroup, then add one to score when checked. The issue is if you keep pressing the correct answer the score just increments. I would like to apply some type of toggle if the answer is changed the points adjust accordingly.

I would like to also clean this code up so it's not so repetitive. Using a new class or method. Though I can't figure out how to implement it.

Main

```
package com.example.samuel.trivaapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    //Score keeper.
    private int score = 0;
    private int correct = 0;
    private int wrong = 0;
    // determines if the selected was right or wrong, then used to add up the score.
     boolean question1 = false;
     boolean question2 = false;
     boolean question3 = false;
//    private boolean question3 = false;
//    private boolean question4 = false;
//    private boolean question5 = false;
//    private boolean question6 = false;
//    private boolean question7 = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RadioGroup rGroup1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.first_question_group);

        RadioButton checkedRadioButton1 = (RadioButton) rGroup1.findViewById(rGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

        rGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {


                if (R.id.correct_answer1 == checkedId) {
                    question1 = true;

                } else {
                    question1 = false;

                }

            }

        });

        RadioGroup rGroup2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.second_question_group);

        RadioButton checkedRadioButton2
                = (RadioButton) rGroup2.findViewById(rGroup2.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

        rGroup2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {


                if (R.id.correct_answer2 == checkedId) {
                    question2 = true;

                } else {
                    question2 = false;

                }

            }

        });

        RadioGroup rGroup3 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.third_question_group);

        RadioButton checkedRadioButton3
                = (RadioButton) rGroup3.findViewById(rGroup3.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

        rGroup3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {


                if (R.id.correct_answer3 == checkedId) {
                    question3 = true;

                } else {
                    question3 = false;

                }

            }

        });


    }
    //used to diplay the players previous score on screen.
    public void displayScore() {
        TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score_keeper);
        score = correct + wrong;
        scoreView.setText(Integer.toString(correct));

    }




    //used to submit results with button and tally score.
    public void submitResults(View view){

        question1();
        question2();
        question3();
        displayScore();
         score= 0;
         correct = 0;
         wrong = 0;
    }


    //selector for radioGroup1 check if id matches correct answer.

    //submit results calls this to find out if the answer was correct for question 1 to use for tally.
    public void question1() {
        if(question1) {
            correct++;
        } else {
            wrong--;
        }


    }




    //submit results calls this to find out if the answer was correct for question 2 to use for tally.
    public void question2() {
        if(question2) {
            correct++;
        } else {
            wrong--;
        }


    }



    //submit results calls this to find out if the answer was correct for question 3 to use for tally.
    public void question3() {
        if(question3) {
            correct++;
        } else {
            wrong--;
        }


    }



}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.samuel.trivaapp.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_logo"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/player_name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header_logo"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/enter_player_name"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/score_board"
        android:layout_below="@+id/player_name"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Score:"
            android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/score_keeper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>



<!--questions scroll view.-->


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/question_scroll_view"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/score_board">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/first_question_group"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Is this question 1? "/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/correct_answer1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Answer 1" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Answer 2" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Answer 3" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Answer 4" />


            </RadioGroup>


        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/test2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/test"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/second_question_group"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Is this question 2? "/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Answer 1" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/correct_answer2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Answer 2" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Answer 3" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Answer 4" />


            </RadioGroup>


        </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/test3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/test2"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/third_question_group"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    >


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Is this question 3? "/>
                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Answer 1" />
                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Answer 2" />
                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/correct_answer3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Answer 3" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Answer 4" />


                </RadioGroup>


            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="submit"
                android:onClick="submitResults"
                android:layout_below="@id/test3"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>


    </ScrollView>





</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, do you have any information on how to do that. I know how listener work with Java by itself to a certain degree, but not setting them up with android.

Comment: Thank you I will try that out. I appreciate it.

Comment: I am not sure where I need to declare this code. It seems crazy if it all goes in the onCreate. If I had multiple questions I would have to do this for each one. I must be missing something.

Comment: Yep, just learning right now. It is really suppose to be a simple project, that is just a quiz app that has 10 questions and  each question has 4 answers and you choose the right one you get a point.

Comment: Hahaha, I can't even figure out how to implement one of these methods for now. I keep getting errors all over the place. At this points it seems like I should make a new listener and class for each object.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking it would make sense to make a question class. I am going to start again from scratch. If you're saying that answer is straight forward and to me it does look like what I need, but I must've of mistype something.

Comment: Thank You Mike!, I finally got it to work. I really appreciate you helping me gather what I needed.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know, even though I implemented everything, it still doesn't calculate points correctly no matter what type of statements I use. It can always be tricked to keep gaining points to every click.

Comment: I did remove those, keep in mind I am using 4 radiobuttons if that makes a difference. Also just wondering is it normal for me to be working on something like this for 10 hours?

Comment: I added what I did if you can look at it above in original question. I did a ton of different variations of that if statement, so I am  sure the logic is off somewhere that I am not seeing. Also when I click the correct answer from the start it doesn't trigger the addition until I check another item first then go back to the right answer.

Comment: I do think I have a simple work around for a simple logic fix. It's not by any means perfect, but I think it can work. Though I can't seem to get the initial click that starts to register. Is there some type of other listener I can implement, because currently only when it changes doesn't it register the points.

Comment: When it loads there is no items selected then when no matter what item I click the first click never fires.

Comment: Sorry, I actually do have it to update after button is clicked public void submitResults(View view){
        question1();
        displayScore();

Comment: The radiobuttons all start off blank then the first click on one doesn't register anything until I click through an extra button. I am going try log now also see if says anything.

Comment: Well the log at least confirmed it isn't doing anything when I click originally. I really am amazed how long this button to implement is taking, I feel like this is such a common thing to do.

Comment: I reconfigured it to the state I had when it was working on first click, but yeah the logic to actually not get the points to keep adding on each other click needs work. Thanks for your time I might have to call it a night on this problem.

Comment: It's not anything like that. I think the thing that just throwing me all over the place is like what you were saying I need figure out how loop over answers and do some type of reset so when answer changes the points reflect correctly. I believe that might be the thing throwing me so aloof.

Comment: I think I am just going to make a couple classes and use a boolean to keep track of the questions and then add all the trues as +1 and false -1. This way the boolean will always update, but no calculation until the end. I am sure there is a better way to make this logic, but I am not sure I've seen anything yet, that seems better.

Comment: Hi do you have any idea how I can make this code less repetitive I don’t know why I am having so much trouble figuring this out. https://github.com/raregamer/TrivaApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/samuel/trivaapp/MainActivity.java

Comment: Okay I will switch it back to the other way I had it. Part of reason why I switched it was because I didn’t understand why it matters which one I use and was trying to see if anything simplified.

Comment: Hi if you get a chance please take a look at the new code. I think I might of saw to use an ArrayList to clean things up, but I am not sure how to go about that if it is the correct steps I need to take. https://github.com/raregamer/TrivaApp2/tree/trivia2/app/src/main/java/com/example/samuel/trivaapp  also on a side note if you have an article or any information why it's better to setup the radiobuttons like this compared to the google way I would love to know.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the right link I updated the code in it. Though my issue isn't with the logic right now. I t is to not have the repetitive code, I don't see why I can't figure out how to make a class or store questions and answers better to only have 1 method for each task, I keep trying to use parameters and making classes, but I keep having errors. I just want to simplify this main class.

Comment: I don't know why it is saying that. I just deleted that stuff I change the code just in main topic here to reflect code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I believe I figured out what I wanted to do. If anyone else has this issue or a similar problem, of using multiple RadioGroups I hope this helps.

https://github.com/raregamer/TrivaApp1/tree/trivia2/app/src/main/java/com/example/samuel/trivaapp